# Center and bold the contents of table cells in Apache POI Word document

Tags: java, ms-word, apache-poi, alignment

How can I center and bold the content of the table cells using Apache POI in a Word document? This is the code I use to build the table:

```
XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFTable table = document.createTable();

XWPFTableRow tableRowOne = table.getRow(0);
tableRowOne.getCell(0).setText("CUSTOMER_NAME");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("Kumar");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("CUSTOMER_ID");
tableRowOne.addNewTableCell().setText("123");

XWPFTableRow tableRowTwo = table.createRow();
tableRowTwo.getCell(0).setText("AGE_GENDER");
tableRowTwo.getCell(1).setText("25/M");
tableRowTwo.getCell(2).setText("VISIT_DATE");
tableRowTwo.getCell(3).setText("11/02/2021");

XWPFTableRow tableRowThree = table.createRow(); 
tableRowThree.getCell(0).setText("REFERRED_BY");
tableRowThree.getCell(1).setText("Self");
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In `Word` text formatting is stored in text runs `XWPFRun`. Paragraph alignment is stored in paragraphs `XWPFParagraph`. This also is true for tables. So you need get `XWPFParagraph`s from `XWPFTableCell` and then `XWPFRun`s from the paragraphs. Then you can set paragraph alignment and text formatting.

See [XWPFTableCell](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFTableCell.html) for methods to get `XWPFParagraph`s.

Complete Example:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWordTable {
    
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

  XWPFDocument document = new XWPFDocument();

  XWPFParagraph paragraph = document.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = paragraph.createRun();  
  run.setText("The table:");

  XWPFTable table = document.createTable();
  table.setWidth("100%");
  
  XWPFTableRow tableRow = table.getRow(0);
  tableRow.getCell(0).setText("CUSTOMER_NAME");
  tableRow.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  tableRow.addNewTableCell().setText("Kumar");
  tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  tableRow.addNewTableCell().setText("CUSTOMER_ID");
  tableRow.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  tableRow.addNewTableCell().setText("123");
  tableRow.getCell(3).getParagraphs().get(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

  tableRow = table.createRow();
  tableRow.getCell(0).setText("AGE_GENDER");
  tableRow.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  tableRow.getCell(1).setText("25/M");
  tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  tableRow.getCell(2).setText("VISIT_DATE");
  tableRow.getCell(2).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  tableRow.getCell(3).setText("11/02/2021");
  tableRow.getCell(3).getParagraphs().get(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.RIGHT);

  tableRow = table.createRow(); 
  tableRow.getCell(0).setText("REFERRED_BY");
  tableRow.getCell(0).getParagraphs().get(0).getRuns().get(0).setBold(true);
  tableRow.getCell(1).setText("Self");
  tableRow.getCell(1).getParagraphs().get(0).setAlignment(ParagraphAlignment.CENTER);
  tableRow.getCell(2).setText("");
  tableRow.getCell(3).setText("");

  paragraph = document.createParagraph();

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("CreateWordTable.docx");
  document.write(out);
  out.close();
  document.close();

 }
}
```

Note: This works using current `apache poi 5.0.0`. Former versions had bugs in `XWPFTableCell.setText` so paragraphs and runs were not present after `XWPFTableCell.setText` was called.